# NodeJS web app dashboard not routing to ejs templates

Tags: node.js, express, redis, router

I am using Argon Dashboard with Nodejs I've been working to getting this to actually display something other then a simple html/index page.

I am running `yarn start` it gives me all these express:application/router feedback. Every other router is Red which to me means bad but does not say Warning. But at the last line express:www the linux console freezes.

```
  express:router use '/' cookieParser +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router use '/' serveStatic +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router use '/' session +1ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router use '/' initialize +1ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router use '/' authenticate +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router use '/' <anonymous> +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router use '/' router +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:router use '/' <anonymous> +0ms
  express:router:layer new '/' +0ms
  express:application set "port" to 8000 +50ms
  express:www Listening on port 8000 +7ms
```

Can someone tell me is this normal? What can I do to possible resolve this, is this a Nginx issue?

Comment: those are debug logs from express,  it "freeze" on last line becouse server is listening go to the browser and make request to localhost:8000, should work

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak This was the case I went to the ip:8000. So would I need to use reverseproxy rather then using traditional document root method?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your case, could you be more descriptive and maybe put some code

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak Currently I have nginx set up with a `document root`, so sense express runs on a seprate port I set up nginx to `reverse proxy` instead?

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak Also when I use `yarn start` it doesnt allow me to leave the console. If I do leave the service seems to stop running.

Comment: I think that you can read this https://github.com/i0natan/nodebestpractices/blob/master/sections/production/delegatetoproxy.md